# SharePoint Online - Create Diagram of Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-wiki

I have created an Enterprise Wiki on SharePoint Online to store technical documentation.

I'd like to try and use it as a CMDB (Configuration Management Database), which shows the relationship between different technical components (e.g. server and switch). Each component is a page in this wiki.

Is it possible to show a diagram of which pages link to others? Using incoming and outgoing links? So when someone creates a new page and links to another it shows the relationship.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could tie this into the **Wiki Categories** and drive it through a **Term set** (Managed Metadata Service). This is a common use case for Knowledge Repositories using Enterprise Wiki.

Comment: Interesting idea, all the pages are tagged so this could work. I can't quite work out how I would show that list as a diagram?

Comment: I know you are looking for a quick, maybe OOTB way but I would just read the term set mapping using JSOM (https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/returning-a-sharepoint-2013-termset-in-a-tree-structure-using-javascript#.WW5uOOvyuM9) and then map it to my custom view model (try the different JS based tree view libraries available). Your implementation would not be a full fledged tree view as you just need the immediate successor and precursor, i guess.

Comment: Thank Ransher, really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of tools that can create visual site maps. [Visio](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=visio%20site%20map&FORM=HDRSC2) has this capability, as well as a variety of 3rd party tools.